# Polymer: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'persistent' of undefined

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-2.x, drawer

when I try to hide drawer in Login page it occur error. I use `dom-if` for hiding menubar and according to it's [syntax](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-if) I used `<template>` tag. But it occur error.

Polymer code

```
<!-- Drawer content -->
<template is="dom-if" if="[[_isLogin()]]">
  <app-drawer id="drawer" slot="drawer" swipe-open="[[narrow]]">
    <app-toolbar>Menu</app-toolbar>
    <iron-selector selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name" class="drawer-list" role="navigation">
      <a name="homepage" href="[[rootPath]]homepage">Homepage</a>
      <a name="profile" href="[[rootPath]]profile">Profile</a>
      <a name="temp" href="[[rootPath]]temp">Temp</a>
    </iron-selector>
  </app-drawer>
</template>
```

Script

```
_routePageChanged(page) {
  if(this._isLogin()) {
      // If no page was found in the route data, page will be an empty string.
      // Default to 'homepage' in that case.
      this.page = page || 'homepage';

      // Close a non-persistent drawer when the page & route are changed.
      if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
          this.$.drawer.close();
      }
  } else {
      this.page = 'login';
  }
}
```

Note: `_isLogin()` is there, it return `true` or `false`

Comment: Above error means your drawer has not been rendered yet or dom-if condition is not true. So, `this.$.dawer` is undefined already.

Comment: But drawer is coming after login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see in the docs [here](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#node-finding), the "*Nodes created **dynamically** using data binding (including those in dom-repeat and **dom-if** templates) are not added to the this.$ hash*"

So, since that element is inside a dom-if, you won't be able to use this "shortcut" to get a reference to it. So you'll have to stick with the "old" [getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById), while keeping in mind that you are not querying the document, but the local shadow dom instead. So this:

```
  if (!this.$.drawer.persistent) {
      this.$.drawer.close();
  }
```

could become something like:

```
  var drawer = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('drawer');
  if (drawer.persistent) {
    drawer.close();
  }
```

**UPDATE**: since you're saying that it still doesn't work, I figured I should mention another thing you need to consider. In your code both showing that element and the condition to query for it are the same, returned by the `_isLogin` method.

To be honest, I don't know if what I am about to suggest is the reason or the recommended solution, but I figured you should give it time to actually stamp the element into the page to be able to query for it (to work around the single execution thread and stuff like that). So as a workaround for this you could wrap your code in a [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) callback, like this:

```
setTimeout(() => {
  var drawer = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('drawer');
  if (drawer.persistent) {
    drawer.close();
  }
});
```

Since the second parameter, the timeout, is not provided, you're basically saying "*do this as soon as possible, but not right now*".

Comment: Thanks for your reply sir. I tried as like you suggested `this.shadowRoot.getElementById('drawer');` and print drawer but still I'm getting `null` . then also I check with `document.querySelector('#drawer')` and `Polymer.dom(this).querySelector('#drawer')`. In all cases I got `null` value, in short I'm not getting drawer at any ways. Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Thank you sir... you always rook. @mishu